# Networking between containers in Google Cloud Build

Tags: google-cloud-build

Is there any networking between containers in Google Cloud Build, and if so what is the DNS convention?

For example, in Drone, one can run a server in a detached container then hit that server from another container.

Comment: I have created a similar question with more details. See if this help you 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52046609/communicate-between-two-containers-in-google-cloud-build

Comment: @ManikantanRamachandran thanks! I'll follow your question.