# Communicate between two containers in Google cloud build

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I am running my CI/CD pipeline in Google cloud build. My app has `web` and `wget` containers. I am trying to reach `web` from `wget`

Cloud build internally used `cloudbuild` bridge network while starting containers as steps. So I am expecting these steps to communicate using names. But its failing.

If I create my own docker bridge netwok then they communicating.

I want to know why cloudbuild network is not working as expected.

Please let me know if you know any other ways to establish communication between step containers.

cloudbuild.yaml

```
steps:

- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  id: Web server
  args: ["run", "-d", "--name", "mani", "manikantanr/hostname_ip"]

- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/wget'
  id: wget web mani:8000
  args: ["-qO-", "http://mani:8000"]
```

To understand the cloudbuild internals I used few docker commands.

debug-cloudbuild.yaml

```
steps:

- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  id: Docker Version
  args: ["version"]

- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  id: Docker info
  args: ["info"]

- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  id: Docker volume ls
  args: ["volume", "ls"]

- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  id: Docker volume inspect homevol
  args: ["volume", "inspect", "homevol"]


- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  id: Docker network ls
  args: ["network", "ls"]

- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  id: Docker network inspect cloudbuild
  args: ["network", "inspect", "cloudbuild"]

- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  id: Docker ps before
  args: ["container", "ls", "--no-trunc"]

- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  id: Web server
  args: ["run", "-d", "--name", "mani", "manikantanr/hostname_ip"]
  # waitFor: ['-']

- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/wget'
  id: wget ipinfo
  args: ["-qO-", "https://ipinfo.io"]

- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  id: Docker ps after
  args: ["container", "ls", "--no-trunc"]

- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  id: Docker inspect mani host network
  args: ["inspect", "mani"]

- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  id: Docker alpine ifconfig inside container
  args: ["run", "alpine", "ifconfig"]

- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/wget'
  id: wget mani:8000
  args: ["-qO-", "http://mani:8000"]
```

Comment: I think Cloud Builder runners are pretty basics and they are not intended to run web servers inside. Why do you want to do that? Unit test that requires external service?

Comment: Usually I use unit tests with mocks for external services.

But this time I have a usecase where I had to test with real db containers.So I created a `Postgres` and `Oracle Db`s in new docker network in detached mode. Then started `web` container in same network to communicate with them.

Comment: I am looking for a clean way to do this without a sepearate docker network. I tried starting containers with `cloudbuild` and `host` networks.

Comment: Cloud build is starting containers with names `steps-x` but these are not reachable from other steps.

Comment: What did you end up doing? I'm experiencing the same problem, except that it doesn't even work when I define the network myself, and this is infinitely frustrating!

Comment: @OlaVikholt
I used docker-compose. Started one service with `-d`  and execute my test in another service.

Comment: what would `-d` stands for? I am having a similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63721400/is-it-possible-to-start-pubsub-emulator-from-cloud-build-step

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar issue setting up integration tests on cloud build. I was trying to run integration tests from another builder (go-builder) against my other containers (started through docker-compose community built containers).

Without specifying any networks on docker-compose.yaml, all containers are started on the default network (https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/). On cloud build, it creates a new network named **cloudbuild_default** and places all my containers there. By forcing all containers to join **cloudbuild** network through my docker-compose.yaml file, I was able to establish communications and run my tests against them.

```
#docker-compose.yaml

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: cloudbuild
```

This might be an alternate configuration for you. Hope it helps

Comment: Were you still able to access your service as the OP is showing using the container's name? E.g. just at `http://<container-name>:<port>`?

Answer (score 3):

From [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/overview#build_configuration_and_build_steps):

> Each build step is run with its container attached to a local Docker network named cloudbuild. This allows build steps to communicate with each other and share data.

You can use docker compose and using `cloudbuild` network, for example:

```
#docker-compose.yml
app-workspace:
  ...
  network_mode: cloudbuild
db-mysql:
  ...
  network_mode: cloudbuild
...
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: cloudbuild
```

Or if you are using `docker run`, add option `--network cloudbuild`.

After that, you can communicate to other services you defined in the previous step as you expect. For example:

```
#steps
- id: 'Ping to other container'
  name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/curl
  args: ["app-workspace:your-service-port"]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I like this answer, but unfortunately wasn't able to make it work. Created a minimal reproduction repo: https://github.com/akauppi/cloudbuild-network-experiment

Answer (score 1):

I did an experiment and it looks like (without doing any special setup) you can communicate between build step containers by using the name step_x (0-based numbering).

For example if you have a web-server listening on the endpoint /hello (on port 8081) in the container for the first build step (step_0). You can make requests to that endpoint from another build step container by making a request to http://step_0:8081/hello.

Comment: I tried same thing 3 months ago. I too tried the container hostname `step_x` to connect one container from another. But it did not work as you said. I'm not sure I did everything right then. But I tested the same by creating another network and started my steps in that network, then they were able to communicate. By default steps starts in the network called `cloudbuild` I tried starting containers in the same network, even this didn't help.

Comment: I just did a test where I ran this step first:

`- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker`
`args: ['network', 'create', 'cloudbuild-net']`

then if I run the other step containers in that network via option:
`--network cloudbuild-net`

I'm able to get all the step containers to talk to each other based on their names

Comment: Would you happen to have an example? I'm struggling with this at the moment.

Comment: Yes, here is a repo that was set up by someone doing a similar thing:
https://github.com/Philmod/gcb-docker-compose